# Desktop application "internal urls"

Tags: java, design-patterns

For web applications internal navigation, you usually use URLs, with an URL router/dispatcher.

Is there some equivalent pattern/analogy within a desktop app being really navigation intensive/with multiple views?

Let's say I'm in myapp://view1/subview1?state=someState and I then switch in myapp://view2/subview2/, by deconstructing it in the main controller, which decodes the first part, switches the view to view2, then calls the view2 controller with "/subview2", which itself loads "subview2", etc.

I find it to be a really KISS (keep it simple stupid) abstraction for handling "navigation" state.

1. Would this "pattern" be practical or an awful idea?
2. What would be the general plan to implement it in Java? (use URIs? URLs? Strings?)

Comment: Isn't one of the main appeals of making a desktop application the fact you don't really need to think about serialising your state into a string? I mean I agree it's a good idea to have a well-defined model of the state of your app but I'm not sure you get an additional advantage in shoehorning it into an URL, as opposed to using whatever native serialisation mechanism is available to save and restore it.

Comment: Also I think this is OT or too broad since it seems like the question is of the form "hey I thought of a solution, is it good?" without actually saying what problem it solves. I.e. you should start from the basics of what you're trying to accomplish here. For instance, in your example, what if your app has many equivalently important "subviews"? Like, say, a split pane text editor or file browser? Or an email/groupware app that has a sidebar for the mailboxes and another for the calendars?

Comment: (Obviously none of the above is related to having your application serve as a protocol handler which is a different beast altogether. Protocol handlers tend to expose an intentionally limited set of features in a command-oriented structure instead of being a full remote control mechanism.)

Comment: It's a productivity app (tasks, notes, etc.) which is navigation intensive. I'll need to serialize locations when I need to e.g. copy and paste a task (link) inside a note. Hence the idea of app specific urls.

Comment: In that case, are you linking to navigation states or to data items ("resources") in the app? Those would lead to subtly different approaches. I.e. to display a data item you don't necessarily need to restore the entire UI to how it was when the link was created. Conversely, if the URL doesn't encode the entire UI state, it's not sufficient to make it the core of your application's navigation.\

Comment: Also, upon reflection, this use case is basically what I mentioned by having your app serve as a protocol handler. Except for the part where you register it with the OS to do this for outside apps. So what I'm trying to say is that URLs are a fine way to create links to data items in your app or to some commands it can execute. But that that's something else than having your entire app be URL-based, and ultimately doing the latter seems more like a limitation. (For instance, how would you maintain compatibility if the UI of your app changes dramatically while still using a similar data model?)

Comment: "In that case, are you linking to navigation states or to data items ("resources") in the app?" => It's a bit hybrid, because some of my views are search results for example, but I still don't need to reconstruct the whole state of the UI (like the mouse position, focused items, etc.). So I think it's a valid approach (other answers confirmed it's common practise to isolate the navigation behaviour from the rest of the code). Thanx a lot for your comments, helped me clarify a lot. Too bad I can't select those as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Controller pattern might be a good place to start.